# How to alter DOM on dynamic page as elements are added?

Tags: javascript, dom, dom-events, tampermonkey

I have a web page that I am attempting to write a Tampermonkey script for that will find Virtual Terminal (VT) color codes in specific elements and then replace them with `<span>` elements.  I am confident that the core code works fine, but the issue is how I can effectively deploy the code so that as new elements are added to the DOM via the site's own code, mine will detect and rewrite.

```js
(function() {
    'use strict';

    document.addEventListener("DOMNodeInserted",function(){
        setTimeout(function(){
        var vtRe = /\x5b(?<color>\d{2}(?:;1)?|0)m/;
        var nodeList = document.querySelectorAll("div.command-output:not(.vt-colorized)");
        nodeList.forEach((node) => {
            // Replace VT Color Codes with span colors
            var iText = node.innerText;
            var arr = iText.split(/\x1b/);
            node.innerText = '';
            arr.forEach((item) => {
                var newEle = document.createElement("span");
                let match = vtRe.exec(item);
                if (match) {
                    switch(match.groups.color) {
                        case "30":
                            newEle.style.color = 'black';
                            break;
                        case "31":
                            newEle.style.color = 'darkred';
                            break;
                        case "32":
                            newEle.style.color = 'darkgreen';
                            break;
                        case "33":
                            newEle.style.color = 'darkyellow';
                            break;
                        case "34":
                            newEle.style.color = 'darkblue';
                            break;
                        case "35":
                            newEle.style.color = 'darkmagenta';
                            break;
                        case "36":
                            newEle.style.color = 'darkcyan';
                            break;
                        case "37":
                            newEle.style.color = 'darkgray';
                            break;
                        case "30;1":
                            newEle.style.color = 'gray';
                            break;
                        case "31;1":
                            newEle.style.color = 'red';
                            break;
                        case "32;1":
                            newEle.style.color = 'green';
                            break;
                        case "33;1":
                            newEle.style.color = 'yellow';
                            break;
                        case "34;1":
                            newEle.style.color = 'blue';
                            break;
                        case "35;1":
                            newEle.style.color = 'magenta';
                            break;
                        case "36;1":
                            newEle.style.color = 'cyan';
                            break;
                        case "37;1":
                            newEle.style.color = 'white';
                            break;
                        case "32":
                            newEle.style.color = 'green';
                            break;
                        case "0":
                            break;
                        default:
                            break;
                    }
                }
                newEle.innerText = item.replace(vtRe,'');
                node.append(newEle);
            });
            node.classList.add('vt-colorized');
        });
    }, 10000);
    },false);
})();
```

I have tried the following methods:

- `addEventListener("DOMNodeInserted", ...)` to run the code directly as every element is inserted into the DOM; however, this resulted in a call stack exceeded error due to the infinite loop created
- `setInterval(...)` to run the code periodically, looking for the elements that need to be processed by the code; however, this resulted in partial processing or lost data, since the DOM gets changed as the responses come in, which is irregular.
- `addEventListener` → `setTimeout` (as seen in the code above) — this doesn't work either.

Am I going about this the wrong way/is there an easier way to handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mutation events like DomNodeInserted are [deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationEvent).

Use a [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver/MutationObserver) instead.

Simplified example:

```js
const targetNode = document.querySelector("#cont");
const observerOptions = {
  childList: true,
  attributes: false,
  // Omit (or set to false) to observe only changes to the parent node
  subtree: true
}

const observer = new MutationObserver(callback);
observer.observe(targetNode, observerOptions);

function callback(mutationList, observer) {
  mutationList.forEach((mutation) => {
    if (mutation.type === 'childList' && mutation.addedNodes.length) {
      mutation.addedNodes.forEach(el => {
        if (el.matches('#cont ul li')) {
          console.log('<li> Added')
          el.style.color = 'red'
        }
      });
    }
  });
}

// insert an element every 1.5 seconds
let ctr=0;
const timer = setInterval(()=>{   
   if(++ctr===5){     
     clearInterval(timer)
   }
   const li = document.createElement('li')
   li.textContent = `Item ${ctr}`
   document.querySelector('#cont ul').append(li)
},1500)
```

```html
  
<div id="cont">
  <ul>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for this.  Although it's more complicated than a simple event listener, after transitioning my code to using MutationObservers, it already feels a lot more reliable.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the infinite loop, you can set a flag before you add a node that you check inside the listener:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
    let inserting = false;
    document.addEventListener("DOMNodeInserted", function () {
        if (inserting) return;
        inserting = true;
        var vtRe = /\x5b(?<color>\d{2}(?:;1)?|0)m/;
        // ...rest of your code
        inserting = false;
    });
})();
```

Comment: I did try something similar to this first.  I tried checking the `event.relatedNode` to see if its `classList.contains('command-output')` and if not, then return immediately.  But I still get a `Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded.`

Comment: Setting a flag variable would probably be more reliable. Did you try it?

Comment: The flag variable helps with handling the stack size issue.  Thanks for the suggestion!